# Gradient Border fade surrounding div with css/html

Tags: html, css, border, gradient

Hi I was trying to figure out how to create a border that fades into the background colour of a div and this is the only solution I could come up with.
I've googled around and it seems people suggest CSS3 but I was told it was still "under development" and not fully introduced in modern browsers, correct me if I'm wrong, probably am.

Anyway this is the solution I came up with, are there simpler ways of doing it or is this a reasonable approach?

Created numerous divs for each part of the border (as below), and set their background image according to the part of the border: https://i.stack.imgur.com/opACP.png

HTML & CSS: http://codeviewer.org/view/code:1e4f

(New to webdevelopment and stack overflow, sorry if I'm doing anything unorthodox, thanks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as Tim there already said it, if the width of your website is static, you can do something like that ( In fact even if css3 may be good option for your usage case This is super simple... )

http://jsfiddle.net/Xtw84/3/ - this is from a prior answer so the edges are not soft but the idea is the same. ( doesnt matter ) I also added image in the background so you can see how that would work. Theres no need.. actually makes no sense to slice the background image in half.

Heres a bit more stripped down version of it. http://jsfiddle.net/Xtw84/4/

---

With css3 i would do this with box-shadow and just expand the shadow as much as needed.

Comment: Yes that's the CSS3 solution I found.

Answer (score 0):

Is your layout going to be fluid? e.g. it will grow in width/height? If it isnt going to grow in width, then there is no reason that you can not just set the background image.

For what you are doing, I wouldn't use gradient borders and just stick with the images in the background.

Comment: It won't grow in width, but it will in height, and that's why I just used "100%", so that it'd change with the browser's height. If it grows in width, can't I just set the top border and width border to be 100% of the container so that'd change along with the browser too?
Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @LylatWars So, you want the content area to always "stretch" to the bottom even if actual content height doesnt reach to the bottom? In my answer which is more or less same one as Tim's answer but with an example.. In it the content area does have fluid height and the height of it is determined by the amount of the content.

Comment: @Lollero, Ah I get you, sorry tad slow, splitting it into 3 images would handle the fluid height, I'm assuming the way I've done it also handles fluid width, but most of the time it's not really needed to have a fluid width... alrighty, thanks.

Comment: @LylatWars Yes, thats exactly how it is.